# How can I restore my old task with a new one in swift?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, request

I have question about tasks. I need to restore my request, I change link and fetch some new data to that link and show them on my table view. User can change link according to picker view, I have a variable for it and I replaced in link and thats working correct too but in second request can make a thread I assume it is very bad question but I am new in swift. How can I make second or more request in one function.

Here my function code :

```
func fetchArticles(){

      let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "my_api_link_is_here")!)

      let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (Data,URLResponse,Error) in

          if Error != nil {
              print(Error!)
          }

          self.articles = [Article]()

          do{
              let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]

              if let articlesFromJson = json["articles"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {


                  for articleFromJson in articlesFromJson {
                      let article = Article()

                    let source = articleFromJson["source"] as![String: AnyObject]

                    let name = source["name"]

                    if let title = articleFromJson["title"] as? String, let author = name as? String , let desc = articleFromJson["description"] as? String, let url = articleFromJson["url"] as? String, let imageToUrl = articleFromJson["urlToImage"] as? String  {


                        article.author = author as String


                        if articleFromJson.index(forKey: "description") != nil {
                            article.desc = desc as String
                        }else{
                            article.desc = "empty"
                        }

                        article.headline = title as String
                        article.imageUrl = imageToUrl as String
                        article.url = url as String


                    }

                    self.articles?.append(article)

                  }


              }

              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.tableView.reloadData()
              }


          }catch let Error {
              print(Error)
          }

      }
      task.resume()


  }
```

Comment: Unrelated but `(Data,URLResponse,Error)` are not types, they are parameter labels (instances). To avoid confusion name them lowercased `(data, response, error)`

Comment: @vadian I will change it. Thanks.